# Python Debug Error: No module named flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, modulenotfounderror

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////mydatabase.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I'm trying to run above code which is taken from flask docs for create database file.
when i run this code(filename **app.py**) in VS Code editor i got below error.

```
PS C:\Users\HP-360\Desktop\Flask> python
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\HP-360\Desktop\Flask\app.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
>>>
```

I already installed **flask** and **flask-alchemy**. But I got **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'**.
Please anyone help me to solve this error

Comment: Please add the output of `python -m pip list` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\HP-360\Desktop\Flask\app.py`

Rename your `Flask` folder to something else. Modules in python are just folders with scripts, your folder is called Flask and python is trying to import it as a module.